# WPF: Unable to raise Window.Closing event from app module

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, prism

I take charge of a development of an older WPF modular application using [Prism Library for WPF](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Modules.html). In this case, entry point to the application for me is an overriden Initialize() method since I have no access to the [Application.MainWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.mainwindow)'s App class. This class along with some other helper classes is compiled to EXE file and DLL's.

Currently I'm facing to a problem that I have to catch the [Window.Closing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing) event which is **not raised** during closing the application. Normally this piece of code which is put into the constructor (in this specific case into Initialize() method) is working as expected

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Closing += (s, e) =>
{
  e.Cancel = true;
};
```

On the other hand, event [Window.Closed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closed) is fired up without any issues.

In my opinion it's not possible to associate this event handler outside of [Application.MainWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.mainwindow)'s constructor, or do I something wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was located. The [OnClosing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.onclosing) method which raises the [Closing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing) event is implemented in the shell and it looks like this

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
     e.Cancel = true;
     ViewModel.StartShutdownSequence();
}
```

The `StartShutdownSequence()` encapsulates some logic regarding handling individual modules and at the end it calls `Application.Current.Shutdown()` which definitely shutdown the application.